# ¿argumento no es opcional?

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo este error que no me deja avanzar en el programa, soy principiante en esto de la programación, a continuación dejo un fragmento del código.

```
  Function VeriryInputRange(worksheets As Double) As Boolean

Worksheet = Sheets("welldata") Row = ActiveCell.Row Count = Selection.Rows.Count If (Row >= 6 And Row <= 18 And Row + Count <= 18
+ 1) Then
    VeriryInputRange = True Else
    VeriryInputRange = False End If

Worksheet = Sheets("completiondata") Row = ActiveCell.Row Count = Selection.Rows.Count If (Row >= 6 And Row <= 18 And Row + Count <= 18
+ 1) Then
    VeriryInputRange = True Else
    VeriryInputRange = False End If

End Function

Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'Verify input data range
*If (Not VeriryInputRange(worksheets As Double)) Then* MsgBox ("Please select the line with the well data") Exit Sub End If
```

Comment: Cambia: `If (Not VeriryInputRange(worksheets As Double)) Then` por: `If (Not VeriryInputRange(2)) Then` Siendo ese 2 el número de hojas.

Comment: muchas gracias!